# How to swipe tabs to change the data?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

How to swipe the tabs like  swipe to move "One Page" to "Another page"? (google store play - like).   Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/saravmajestic/ionic/tree/master/tabbedSlideBox

Answer (score 1):

You can use TouchSwipe.js in your project. The code is below:

```
$("body").swipe({
  swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
   $(this).text("You swiped " + direction );
 }
 });
```

and the link is this: http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Basic_swipe.html

Comment: May be it's correct, whatever u commented it's related to JQuery. But it not related to IONIC framework and AngularJS.